¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi página de github use XAMPP?
He subido mi página de github pero los request no funcionan. Si alguien sabe algo se lo agradecería.

Github es solo para paginas estáticas. En resumen, solo HTML y otras cosas pero no usa PHP. Por cierto XAMPP es para desarrollo local. Si quieres que tu web con PHP este en internet, debes buscar un hosting.

El hosting de páginas en github pages es para páginas estaticas o SPA usando javascript. Para páginas dinamicas que utilicen php se puede usar Hostinger por ejemplo.

Github pages solo sirve para sitios estáticos es decir solo html/css. Si quiere subir un proyecto de prueba o para portafolio de php le recomiendo 000webhost yo lo he usado y es bueno además de ser gratis

Gracias por la ayuda!
